# Dependencies and mongodb on linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, dependencies, build-dependencies

Don't really understand why under Ubuntu, each time I try to run

> ldd mongodb

(v3.0.7), I get this:

```
   ./mongod: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10: version `libssl.so.10' not found (required by ./mongod)
   ./mongod: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by ./mongod)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffeeb589000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1d9175e000)
        libssl.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f1d914ff000)
        libcrypto.so.10 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007f1d91124000)
...
```

ldd has found libcrypto and libssl but still displays errors telling me... It cannot find libcryto and libssl !??

Comment: Is it possible you somehow have mongo configured for SSL, and trying to fire it up in non SSL ready setup?  It looks like this `libcrypt` module is for SSL, not sure if just SSL though.  So that makes me ask, are you sure your mongodb has been installed correctly?  Does it work on any other installation that you have?   Is this helpful? https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/

Comment: sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

Comment: libssl-dev is already the newest version